# Error de corrida proyecto calculadora VBA

Tags: vba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Porque me sale eso ?
al hacer la corrida me vota ese error pero no se porque, me podrian ayudar ?

Comment: ¿Cuál error? Escríbelo y no lo muestres como imagen, ya que no todos podrán visualizarla correctamente. Lee [ask].

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.